# Can I POST data to a Google Web App without having to authenticate?

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I'm trying to POST data to a Google Web App to automatically enter some tedious data. Whenever I try I get a response back asking me to log in, the Web App is deployed to be accessible by anyone.

Can I POST data to the form without authentication? If not, what type of authentication is required?

Edit: Quick code sample I threw together:

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var keyValue = new NameValueCollection();
            keyValue.Add("agentName", "John Doe");
            keyValue.Add("dayOff", "Sunday");
            keyValue.Add("startTime", "8:00 AM");
            Uri uri = new Uri("mywebapp url");
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", keyValue);
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

Comment: Do you have code you can share? The documentation mentions supporting POST, so I don't see why it shouldn't work. Also - is the web app set to execute as you? If not, that's likely the issue.

Comment: Hey Jens, I have deleted the method I was using to test this. It's fairly simple, make a WebClient, make a Uri, pass in a NameValueCollection and get the response. The response I was getting back was asking me to log in. If I try and just go to my Web App in a browser I cannot access it unless I log into a google account. The account doe snot matter, just has to be any google account. The Web app is set to execute as myself. I added a quick code example.

Comment: Can you post the Apps Script code (e.g. the content of the `doGet` and/or `doPost` functions) that you are using?  Which URL are you using?  (It should end in `/exec`.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow anyone to execute your script, even if they are not signed in to a Google account, you need to use the following settings in the *"Deploy as web app"* dialog:

1. **Project version:**  if in doubt, select *"New"* to ensure that you are deploying the latest copy of the script's code.
2. **Execute the app as:**  select *"Me"*.  This ensures that the "even anonymous" option will be available.
3. **Who has access to the app:** select *"Anyone, even anonymous"*.  (Note that if you select *"Anyone"*, only users that are signed-in to a Google account will be able to execute your script.)

Once you have selected these options, click the "Update" button and copy the script URL.  It should look like `https://script.google.com/a/macros/<APPS DOMAIN>/s/<SCRIPT KEY>/exec`.  At this point an unauthenticated GET or POST to the script's URL should be successful.

Be aware that the script's execution will count against **your** daily Apps Script quota.

Comment: Hi kiwidrew, thanks for the reply. As previously stated, I have deployed the web app already. However I do not have the option to select `Anyone, even anonymous`. There are only three options. Only myself, anyone within my domain, or anyone. Is this a restriction set by the domains administrators?

Comment: So you have chosen "Execute the app as:  me", but there is still no "even anonymous" option?  I suppose it is possible that the domain administrator has a way to disable this...

Comment: @douglasg14b Ah, there we go - you have domain restrictions. You would need to speak to your admin about that...

Comment: @JensAstrup, after some further investigating I am not sure that the domain admin can block this.  I'm the domain admin for a (free) Google Apps domain and definitely don't have an option that would control this.  Perhaps it is different for the paid version of Google Apps for Work?

Comment: @kiwidrew I know the admin can restrict access to files to only those within the domain - which might affect the scripts?